# Is it possible to get inconsistent data when using Amazon RDS read replicas?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Imagine the following scenario:

1. You are using a web application to modify your profile data (let's say you change your name from **A** to **B**).
2. The data is stored in Amazon RDS. You configured your DB to use additional read replicas.
3. Once you submitted the update of your data (**B**), you refresh the page immediately.
4. You see the old data (**A**) being read from Amazon RDS (pulled from not yet synchronized read replica).

Is the scenario described above possible to get? How likely it is?

I know that Amazon RDS read replicas do not guarantee strict read-after-write consistency, but that way you might have a really bad user experience. How you should design your app to cope with such issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to hit (query) the read replica with stale data. Nevertheless it is not very likely in your described way. Replication normally needs under a second. And refreshing a page needs a bit :)

Replication speed depends on the load (mainly on the read replica).

To avoid strange behaviours in your case:

1. If you really need consistent reads after a write, just read from the master! But I don't see this in your described use case. Try to monitor that, if you wanna proof.
2. Don't put additional load to your read replica (like reporting or analytic queries). This might slow down the replication.
3. You can use Amazon Aurora to possible get an even better sync for (read) replicas.

There are even more methods to complicate things and make it "better". But normally, you think about these with large systems, with heavy write/update load.